# Homotopically equivalent to Čech nerve?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I see a theorem without proof on Gelfand & Manin:

> Suppose $\mathfrak U=\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is a locally finite open covering of the topological space $X$ such that each finite intersection $U_{\alpha_1}\cap\dotsc\cap U_{\alpha_n}$ is contractible. Then $X$ is homotopically equivalent to the [Alexandrov-Čech nerve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_of_a_covering) $N(\mathfrak U)$.

I need a reference of a sketch of a proof for the preceding theorem. In fact, the following theorem (Theorem 13.4) of Bott & Tu is a corollary of this:

> Suppose the topological space $X$ has a good cover $\mathfrak U$. Then the fundamental group of $X$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group $\pi_1(N(\mathfrak U))$ of the nerve of the good cover.

Maybe the idea of the proof also applies to the stronger theorem.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: There's a proof of this fact (in the category of CW-complexes, at least) in section 4.G of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology." The basic idea is to construct an explicit map $X \to N(\mathfrak{U})$, then use Whitehead's theorem to show that it's a homotopy equivalence. That proof crucially uses paracompactness, though. I'm not sure how to get rid of that assumption, but it's at least a place to start.

Comment: @anomaly I skimmed the proof and maybe the paracompactness is only used to give a partition of unity? It seems to me that the local finiteness of $\mathfrak U$ gives a partition of unity. I haven't gone through homotopy theory. I only want a reference to see what's the idea involved. Thanks!

Comment: Looking over the proof again, you're right about the use of paracompactness, and you do get the partition for free because of local finiteness. Hatcher's proof should work, then, but you're going to need some sort of machinery to prove that the map you construct is a homotopy equivalence. Good luck!

Comment: @anomaly Well, I need time to read it. Please post an answer here so that I can accept it. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happpy to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a proof of this fact (in the category of CW-complexes, at least) in section 4.G of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology." The basic idea is to construct an explicit map $X\to N(\mathfrak{U})$, then use Whitehead's theorem to show that it's a homotopy equivalence. The proof uses paracompactness, but it's only used to construct a partition of unity; the local finiteness condition gives you that for free.

Comment: Indeed, one has to assume $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex since $N(\mathfrak{U})$ does. In general one can only expect to have a weak equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch using the language of homotopy colimits. Hatcher uses a slight variation of this using $\Delta$-sets as opposed to simplicial sets, where his geometric realization coincides with the "fat realization."

Let $\mathscr U = \{U_j\}_{j \in J}$ be an open cover $X$. Suppose that $X$ is paracompact and that all the nonempty finite intersections in $\mathscr U$ are contractible.

Associated to every open cover there is an abstract simplicial complex called the nerve of the cover, written $K = N(\mathscr U)$, that has vertices to be the set $J$, and simplicies the finite subsets $\emptyset \neq I \subseteq J$ such that $U_I \neq \emptyset$.  Every simplicial complex can be viewed as a category with objects the set of simplicies and morphisms the inclusions of simplicies.

Define the functors $F, G : K^{\text{op}} \to \textbf{Top}$ as follows. Define $F$ on objects by $F(\sigma) = U_\sigma$ and on morphisms by $\sigma \subseteq \sigma'$ maps to the inclusion $U_{\sigma'} \to U_\sigma$. Define $G$ to be the constant functor on the space with one object $\{*\}$.

Now we can define a natural transformation $\tau : F \Rightarrow G$ by $\tau_\sigma : U_\sigma \to \{*\}$ which by hypothes is a pointwise homotopy equivalence. The natural transformation $\tau$ induces a map on the homotopy colimits, $\tau_* : \operatorname{hocolim} F \to \operatorname{hocolim} G$, which is a homotopy equivalence (since pointwise homotopy equivalence implies homotopy equivalence on the homotopy colimits; for a detailed proof see Theorem 8.3.7, p. 409, *Cubical Homotopy Theory* by Munson, Volić).

For the first functor, $F$, we have, 
$$
\operatorname{hocolim} F = \vert \operatorname{srep}_\bullet F \vert = 
\bigsqcup_{n \geq 0} \bigsqcup_{\sigma_0 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \sigma_n} U_{\sigma_n} \times \Delta^n / \sim.
$$
Dugger [*Hypercovers in Topology*, p. 6] shows that this is homeomorphic to (the realization of) the ordered Čech complex, $\check C_\bullet^{\text{ord}}(\mathscr U)$ using a neat coordinatization of the barycentric subdivision of the $k$-simpicies, in effect, 
$$
\Bigg (\bigsqcup_{n \geq 0} \bigsqcup_{\sigma_0 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \sigma_n} U_{\sigma_n} \times \Delta^n \Bigg) / \sim 
\quad \cong \quad 
\Bigg(\bigsqcup_{k \geq 0} \bigsqcup_{j_0 \leq \cdots \leq j_k} U_{j_0, \ldots, j_k} \times \operatorname{sd} \Delta^k \Bigg)/ \sim.
$$
The standard argument then, found in Dugger, Hatcher, tom Dieck, shows that $\vert \check C_\bullet^{\text{ord}}(\mathscr U) \vert \simeq X$ when $\mathscr U$ admits partitions of unity, which occurs here since $X$ is paracompact by hypothesis.

For the second functor, $G$, we have 
$$
\operatorname{hocolim} G = \vert \operatorname{srep}_\bullet G \vert = \vert N_\bullet(K) \vert \cong \vert SS_\bullet(K) \vert \cong \vert N(\mathscr U) \vert.
$$
where $N_\bullet(K)$ is the nerve of the category $K$ as a simplicial set, and $SS_\bullet(K)$ is the natural simplicial set associated to every abstract simplicial complex as described in Weibel [Example 8.1.8, p. 258]. The first homeomorphism, $\vert N_\bullet(K) \vert \cong \vert SS_\bullet(K) \vert$, follows from the same subdivision trick used by Dugger. The second follows using the definition of the realization of an abstract simplicial complex, or alternatively, you could take this to be the definition of the realization of a simplicial complex.

Hence,
$$
X \simeq \operatorname{hocolim} F \simeq \operatorname{hocolim} G \cong \vert N(\mathscr U) \vert,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Essentially, if $X$ is good enough, and $f\colon Y\to X$ is an effective morphism, then we can recover $X$ by the geometric realization of the Čech complex $C(f)$ (a kind of descent). Here we take $Y$ to be the disjoint union of $U_\alpha$.